# Changing text color in Listview using SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-viewbinder

I've listed the names from database using `SimpleCursorAdapter` and I want to change the color of a particular name using `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`'s method. I've a problem while running this method, my database contains different names but the `ListView` will display all the namse as one particular name. What am I doing wrong? How to change the text color of a specific name? Is it possible using `ViewBinder`?

This is my part of of code for `ViewBinder`:

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] temp = dh.return_result();
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv = (TextView) view;
        for(int i = 0; i<temp.length; i++)
        {
            if(temp[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Ameer Zhann"))
            {
                tv.setText(temp[i]);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(58, 58, 224));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

and this is my output image:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){    
    int getIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Name");
    String empname = cursor.getString(getIndex);
    tv = (TextView) view;
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setText(empname);
    if(empname.equals("Any String"))
    {                   
        tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(58, 58, 224));
        return true;
    }
    return false;           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Code do exactly what you ask - for every element in `Cursor` you go through all list and set text of each element. I think that "Ameer Zhann" is last result in your list, so only this text left in `TextView`.

Method `setViewValue(...)` called for every element of `Cursor`. So, you don't need any cycle, just fill text with cursor value `tv.setText(Cursor.getString(...));`.

Also there is something strange with this code:

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv = (TextView) view;
```

`view` that comes as param - is already view with id `R.id.textView1` - so just remove call of `findViewById`.

Comment: If i remove the findViewById means, it'll affect the listview not the textview. So, this is important

Answer (score 1):

try with the else part

```
if(temp[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Ameer Zhann")){
    tv.setText(temp[i]);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(58, 58, 224));
}else{
    tv.setText(temp[i]);
}
```

and at the end return true instead of false

Comment: Yes, this else part also important. Thanks